# Почему datetime.strptime не меняет формат, а копирует значение 1 аргумента во все строки Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame Views, который содержит Series: Email, Role, Topics, Date. В Date приведены строки вида '2016/01/09'. Используя метод datetime.strptime я хочу конвертировать эти строки в даты, но вместо нужного мне результата я получаю замену значений строк на одно значение в формате даты: '2016/01/09', которое является первым аргументом метода. Вопрос, как нужно написать чтобы строки меняли только формат, а не значение?

```
views.Date = datetime.strptime('2016/01/09', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь векторизированным методом [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
         email        date
0  aaa@aaa.aaa  2016/01/09
1  bbb@bbb.bbb  2016/11/11
2  ccc@ccc.ccc  2016/12/30

In [23]: df.dtypes
Out[23]:
email    object
date     object    # dtype: object (string)
dtype: object

In [24]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
         email       date
0  aaa@aaa.aaa 2016-01-09
1  bbb@bbb.bbb 2016-11-11
2  ccc@ccc.ccc 2016-12-30

In [26]: df.dtypes
Out[26]:
email            object
date     datetime64[ns]    # dtype: datetime64
dtype: object
```

Comment: MaxU, большое спасибо, решил проблему вашим способом!

Comment: @DenisNovik, всегда рад помочь :)